# Get xmlHttpRequest request size

Tags: javascript, browser, xmlhttprequest

How can I get the request size from xmlHTTPRequest object after .send() call?

I want to collect requests/responses sizes stat. Response stat I can get from `event.total` loadend-event. But where I can find full request size?

Comment: you can more easily find it on the server - or is it just the request body size you want, not including the request headers?

Comment: Heh, I wanna stat of all outcoming requests from my website. I wrote xmlHTTPRequest wrapper and fetch wrapper to proxing all requests and send stat, that's why I can't just use server to catch requests sizes